# Xcode 9.2 no longer providing auto complete features on one project but it does on another?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 9.2.  For one project i have open there is auto complete enabling, but for another project that i am running it is some how disabled.  Below are examples but this disabling of auto complete affects auto completion of functions etc...which is a real pain.

Example. Trying to import UIKit:
[image]

On my other project is is how it should be:

[image]

Comment: you mean the project folder within DerivedData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xcode** is a capricious child. Be patient.

Clean build, delete derived data (Preferences -> Location -> Arrow next to Derived Data), re-launch Xcode.

Auto completion will finally come back.

Moreover, **FYI**, if you have a project actually running, you should cancel the run, I realized that Auto Completion come faster when no project are running.